# Replace quotes in String

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I have to replace all the commas that are between double quotes with a dot. 
I'm trying to do that with the replace and replaceAll Java's methods. But I still didn't sort out a solution.
Can someone help me?

**EDIT:**
I have to manually parse a csv file to object. So I'm trying to string split each input line, but one number has a comma inside so i'm getting more datas than I need for the split.
Example: I have to split this string.

> """LASER MEDIA SOCIETA' COOPERATIVA""",CNF146010,FM  (S),PIAZZA UMBERTO I - PISTICCI,MT,40N2323,16E3328,383,,"99,1",CITY RADIO,"H: --V: 32 dBW",0.0

Notice that I have "99,1" and the ,, before that are putting me in trouble.

```
Scanner var = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader ("t1.csv")));
     ArrayList<Catasto> obj = new ArrayList();
     String data = var.nextLine();
     String data2 = null;
     String full = null;
     int j = 0;
     while (var.hasNextLine()) {
         data = var.nextLine();
         data2 = var.nextLine();
         full = data + data2;
         //full = full.replaceAll("\"*[,]*\"", "."); attempt 1
         System.out.println(full);
         ArrayList<String> parts = new ArrayList();
         String[] parti = full.split(",");
         //for (int i = 0; i<parti.length; i++) {  this is because I'm trying to change empty string with a null
         //if (parti[i] == " ")                    in order to solve this error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
         //      parti[i] = null;                  
         //}
         for (int i = 0; i<12; i++) {
                 parts.add(parti[i]);
         }
         Catasto foo = new Catasto(parts);
         obj.add(foo);
    }
     var.close();
```

**EDIT 2:**
I have solved the problem of the comma between the double quotes. But I don't know why the error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Comment: What issue are you getting with your current solution?

Comment: Show some code to see whats wrong

Comment: @BugsForBreakfast here it is

Comment: @Lauqz that NumberFormatException is because you can't cast "" to a Number, gotta do something with ""

Comment: Thank you Bugs, I solved it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to struggle to do it with a single replaceAll or replace as you need to determine pairs of quotes. Your best bet is to match pairs of quotes and the use replaceAll for the group to change the comma to a full stop.

```
   String input = "\"One,Two,There\",\"Four,Five,Six\"";

   Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\"[^\"]*\"").matcher(input);
   StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
   while(m.find()) {
       m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group().replaceAll(",", "."));
   }
   m.appendTail(sb);

   String output = sb.toString(); // "One.Two.There","Four.Five.Six"
```

Comment: Thank you, that works correctly. Can you help me even with the second problem above? I'm really struggling with that